# Gmap Location in views - exposed filter by distance/proximity and post code

Tags: views, google-maps

I am currently working with **Drupal 7** and **[Location 7.x-3.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/location)** module

I have created a **view**, choose the **Gmap** format, and added the **post code** and **distance** field in **filter** section, so that the visitors are able to search for the locations they want.

Gmap Settings:

> Data Source = **Location.module**
>
> Marker handling = **Use single marker type**

Here is my configuration for the **Location: Distance / Proximity** :

> Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it = **1**
>
> Filter type to expose = **Distance / Proximity**
>
> Operator = **Proximity (Circular)**
>
> Postal code = **Blank**
>
> Distance = **Blank**
>
> Origin = **Postal Code (assume default country)**
>
> Filter identifier = **distance**

After saving the changes, the result is not changing. Is anyone knows what's wrong with my configuration above? Please help..

Comment: What do you mean by "the result is not changing"? Do you mean when a user entersa value into the exposed filter and submits it doesn't work, or something else?

Comment: Also it's worth pointing out that this doesn't relate to the gmap module, it relates to the location module. What version of the location module are you using.

Comment: Hi Rooby, I'm currently using 7.x-3.4

When I hit submit, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get errors or no results when there should be some or results that shouldn't be there?

Comment: There's no errors at the moment. The display of the pointers in the map are as is when I hit submit. There is no change in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to say for sure but my guess is that you have missed a step when installing the location module.

For post code proximity searching the location module uses a database of postcodes and their coordinates to convert the postcode to the lat/lon coordinates that are then used to calculate whether other locations fall in the request distance.

See installation step 6 in the INSTALL.txt file of the location module.

> 6. (Optional) Import a postal codes database for the countries served by your    website, to support proximity searches and other useful
>      features. Postal    code databases may be found in the "databases/"
>      sub-directory of the    Location module directory. The files are in
>      the format of zipcodes.CC.mysql,    where CC is a two-letter country
>      code such as 'us' or 'de'.
>
>    Note: If your site is using table prefixes, you will need to adjust
>      for this    manually, by opening the file in a text editor and
>      replacing 'zipcodes' with    'prefix_zipcodes' throughout.
>
>    To import the files from the command line, enter the following:
>
>    cd sites/SITENAME/modules/location
>       mysql -u username -p database-name < database/zipcodes.us.mysql

Note that this proximity functionality may not work for some countries if the data is not available.

Comment: Hi Rooby, it works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help :)